# how to save an x509 certificates securely?

Tags: c#, xml, ssl, x509certificate

I have a class that has the below implementation:

```
public class ObjectSer
    {
        public X509Certificate cer;
        public string name;
    }
```

I want to serialize an instance of `ObjectSer` in an XML file using `System.Xml.Serialization;` to be loaded later in other application. When I checked the output file there is only the `name` attribute. 
After some [researches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxz81eb9(v=vs.110).aspx) I found out that I should export the certificate to byte[], so I modified the `ObjectSer` Implementation:

```
public class ObjectSer
    {
        public X509Certificate cer;
        public string name;
        public byte[] exportedBytes;
    }
```

Now, I can save and load the certificate, but I don't want to store the certificate exported bytes in an XML file as plain text. My Questions are:

1. For cyber security measures is there any other approaches to perform the serialization and serialization of an X509Certifacate instance ?
2. Should I add another layer to encrypt the `exportedBytes` before saving them and to decrypt before loading them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to serialize an X509Certificate to XML, but in general I'd say don't. If you insist on doing that I recommend to base64 encode the byte array and save that in your xml.

As for your question regarding security; You should only store the public part of the X509Certificate and keep the private key in another place.

I recommend the following article [Eight tips for working with X.509 certificates in .NET](http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2) which has some great tips.

Comment: I want to serialize an x509Certificate because my application is configurable, user should be able to save and load XML files as a configuration and that configuration includes an object that communicates with servers using certificates. when I export the bytes array and save them into the XML file they are already encoded with base64 by default. Does Base64 encode is enough ? i don't think so ...

Comment: You should probably rethink your configuration object. Windows provides ways to safely manage certificates and their accompanying private keys. Make use of that instead of reinventing the wheel. The article I referenced explains how this works.

Comment: My choice is based on the following items: It should support other platforms. The end-user may have restricted access in his computer, the certificate path can be changed so i need that the application loads an XML file that was previously generated in accessible folder. so I want to avoid any bugs that can be happen of access exceptions or user mis-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can store certificate and its private key encrypted in a file in PKCS 12 format. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867088.aspx) is some info about .NET PKCS 12 API.

Comment: I have already generated the certificate using openssl and the it hasas extension .crt and has "C:\Certificate.crt" as path. When I start my application the object load that certificate and then save the exportedByte to an XML file. I don't want to recall the certificate.crt another time, I just want to read and write that certificate properties from the XML file. Because the Certificate.crt can be removed or removed but the path of the XML file is always the same.